# Does Prism EventAggregator support hot subscription?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, eventaggregator

I am looking to use Prism EventAggregator to communicate between 2 different views and with basic implementation the event publish / subscribe is working fine.
The problem is that Subsribe doesn't receive the initial Publish (so its not really a hot observable) that was done before the new view is initialised.
I am looking to make EventAggregator have 'hot observable' and all new Subscription receive the last published event data.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Prism EventAggregator support hot subscription?

Short answer: No, at least not using the built-in implementation. The subscriber is expected to subscribe *before* any event is published by the publisher.

But you could implement this yourself by overriding the `Publish` and `Subscribe` methods of the `PubSubEvent` or `EventBase` classes to "cache" the event being published.

You'll find the default implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/src/Prism.Core/Events).